# MySQL Subquery On Output Table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm fairly new to subqueries/joins but I need to run a query on a table table that was generated from another query. I know this has probably been asked before, but I have not been able to find an answer that works form me.

Basic info about my queries:

query 1:

```
SELECT ipAddress,userId FROM loginAttempts WHERE browser = 'IE' GROUP BY userId
```

query 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(ipAddress) AS rows,ipAddress FROM loginAttempts GROUP BY ipAddress ORDER BY ipAddress;
```

Mainly I need to preform a search to only show unique values that reach certain criteria then show a count of how many of each unique values are returned from that.

This is a simplified version of my queries, but the loginAttempts table tracks each login attempt from each user, and I need to see how many login attempts were made from each IP address from each user. For example...

```
user1, 5 attempts from x.x.x.4
user1, 2 attempts from x.x.x.5
user2, 10 attempts from x.x.x.4
user2, 2 attempts from x.x.x.6
etc...
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Use both columns in group by

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Group by userid, ipAddress

```
SELECT COUNT(ipAddress) AS rows,ipAddress, userId 
FROM loginAttempts 
GROUP BY ipAddress, userId 
ORDER BY ipAddress
```

Together in group by. I hope this will help you

Comment: @drew: thanks for editing actually I m using mobile and I dont knw is there any option like Ctrl + K?

Comment: one time I scored 201 points on my phone in one day. A nightmare. Funny thing is, I haven't done that again even on a laptop. Sorry, I don't know the short-cut.